# http.h:6:23: fatal error：curl/curl.h：there is no this file/directory

Tags: git, compilation

I download the git package in my CentOS-7:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.0.1.tar.gz
tar xzf git-2.0.1.tar.gz
```

When I compile the git:

```
cd git-2.0.1
make prefix=/usr/local/git all
```

I get the bellow error:

> ```
>   ...
>   CC vcs-svn/svndump.o
>   AR vcs-svn/lib.a
>   LINK git-remote-testsvn
>   CC http.o
>   In file included from http.c:2:0:
>   http.h:6:23: fatal error：curl/curl.h：No such file or directory
>   #include <curl/curl.h>
> ```

Comment: To compile git from sources you need a [lot of dependencies](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ccdcbd54c4475c2238b310f7113ab3075b5abc9c/INSTALL#L110).

Answer (score 6):

Seems you did not install the `curl`.

Use bellow command to install curl

`yum install curl-devel -y`

then retry your compile.