# How do I install this new git version2.8.6 without having `sudo` privileges?

Tags: linux, git, curl, makefile, sudo

I am trying to install a newer version of git (git-2.8.6) from https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/ and when I run `make` command , I get the following error:

```
[usr@serv git-2.8.6]$ make
    * new prefix flags
    CC attr.o
    CC config.o
    CC exec_cmd.o
    CC gettext.o
    AR libgit.a
    LINK git-credential-store
    LINK git-daemon
    LINK git-fast-import
    LINK git-http-backend
    LINK git-imap-send
    LINK git-sh-i18n--envsubst
    LINK git-shell
    LINK git-show-index
    LINK git-upload-pack
    LINK git-remote-testsvn
    CC http.o
In file included from http.c:2:0:
http.h:6:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <curl/curl.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:1935: http.o] Error 1
```

Now I understand that there are multiple `git` dependencies that  need to be installed too from this thread [http.h:6:23: fatal error：curl/curl.h：there is no this file/directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245367/http-h623-fatal-error-curl-curl-h-there-is-no-this-file-directory/61733153) But I don't have `sudo` access to run these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install make libssl-dev libghc-zlib-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext unzip
```

Does anyone have any idea how can I successfully install this new `git` version without having `sudo` privileges at any point?

Comment: Try `./build-git.sh` from https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts. If you don't have write-access even to `/usr/local/` define [`INSTX_PREFIX`](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts#output-artifacts).

Comment: For curl you have two choices: (a) you can turn it off, which means you won't be able to access remote repositories using HTTPS, and a few other things.  But you can still use git locally and you can use remote repositories via SSH; or (b) you can compile all the prerequisites from source yourself, just like you're building Git.  That's what the `build-git.sh` script will help you do.

Comment: @phd I cloned this and now running `./build-git.sh` and it is going on right now meanwhile I wanted to ask, using this how can I set my new git version to 2.8.6?

Comment: Why do you need such an exact version?

Comment: @phd Any version later than 1.8.5 is what I need. But the error with "Curl" still remains with 1.8.5 as well.

Comment: I believe `./build-git.sh` will build you the latest version, currently 2.29 or 2.30. With all necessary dependencies.

Comment: Yes I did that but it fails with `Failed to configure libpsl
Failed to build Public Suffix List library
Failed to build cURL` results.

Comment: `INSTX_PREFIX="$HOME/tmp" INSTX_LIBDIR="$HOME/lib" ./build-git.sh` might work. By default it is trying to output to `/usr/local` and `/usr/local/lib` which still require root.  This is from the readme at https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts